# how to do coping of some file from raw folder to file directory only when android app is installed on devices/emulator

Tags: android

Im using 2 text files and one sqlite database file. These files i placed in res/raw folder and it should be available for devices at run time.  how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can access the files in raw folder by using the methods getResources()       .openRawResource(R.raw.mytxt); I have tried it with txt files but not with sqlite database file. You try it and tel the answer.

Sample code is 
`String FILENAME = "hello_filess";
                String string = "hello world!";
                try {

```
                InputStream is = getResources()
                        .openRawResource(R.raw.mytxt);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(is));
                FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME,
                        Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                String strLine = "";
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    fos.write(strLine.getBytes());
                }
                fos.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }`
```

[And for futhur clarification go through this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Hope it could be useful.